# i want to upgrade my joomla version with viruemart component

Tags: joomla2.5, upgrade, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I want to update/upgrade my joomla version and virtue-mart component as well.now my joomla version is 1.5.26 and my virtue-mart component version 1.1.9 and i want to convert into joomla 2.5 and virtue-mart latest version 2.0.6.

But main problem is that i want to update/upgrade joomla and virtue-mart with data.(like users,product,category,orders etc..) i have wonder many site also virtue-mart official site. I have found many solution but when i fallow all the instructions and doing my local machine. then old data f virtue-mart will remove but i want to hold old data and update/upgrade on new version.

So please help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade your J1.5 site with [Jupgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658), which creates a duplicate site in a new directory, then follow the process [here](http://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/virtuemart/wiki/Upgrading_VM1_to_VM2_with_provided_packages) to upgrade VirtuMart.

If you find that your VirtuMart Data still hasn't migrated, it's fairly easy to export those tables through PHPmyadmin and import them to the J2.5 database. Then you should be able to run the VirtuMart upgrade installation.

Comment: i have doing as you mention but in jupgrade not getting virtuemart field